# Ignoring the parameters for define macro with function name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, c-preprocessor

Today, I heard some devil things that C++ programmer could done through `#define` keyword. For example,

```
#define private public
#define class struct
#define sizeof(x) (sizeof(x) - 1)
#define true (__LINE__ % 2)
#define pthread_mutex_lock(m) 0
```

I am interested with the `function definition`. So I try to test it through

```
CRITICAL_SECTION g_critSec;
#define InitializeCriticalSection(n, y) 0


void comparemutexwithcriticalsection() {
    InitializeCriticalSection(&g_critSec);

    std::cout << "Iterations: " << g_cRepeatCount << "\n\r";
    // other codes...
}
```

It can be built successfully under VS2013, and here are the disassemble codes.

```
void comparemutexwithcriticalsection() {
00F9A710  push        ebp  
00F9A711  mov         ebp,esp  
00F9A713  sub         esp,0CCh  
00F9A719  push        ebx  
00F9A71A  push        esi  
00F9A71B  push        edi  
00F9A71C  lea         edi,[ebp-0CCh]  
00F9A722  mov         ecx,33h  
00F9A727  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
00F9A72C  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi]  
    InitializeCriticalSection(&g_critSec);

    std::cout << "Iterations: " << g_cRepeatCount << "\n\r";
00F9A72E  push        0FB66F4h  
    InitializeCriticalSection(&g_critSec);
```

**It seems the parameters are ignored in `#define` macros, am I right?**

---

Based on above, I try to `define` my own function as `0`

```
#define myfunc(a) 0

void myfunc(int a)
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```

However, it failed to compiled under VS2013. **Could someone help me to figure out something missing here? or something wrong on my thought?**

Comment: If the code has `#define InitializeCriticalSection(n, y) 0`, then `InitializeCriticalSection(&g_critSec);` must generate an error. If you seem to be getting different results, please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: This may be some sort of MSVC "extension"

Answer (score 1):

First let's be very clear that redefining language keywords like `private` is undefined and may behave in a wide variety of ways.

Then, as to your function the problem is that you create the `#define` *before* you define the function. Try it this way:

```
void myfunc(int a)
{
    cout << a << endl;
}

#define myfunc(a) 0
```

If you do it the way you originally proposed, you'd wind up with this after preprocessing, while is pretty clearly illegal:

```
void 0(int a)
{
    cout << a << endl;
}
```